# display HTML string in any control of web page

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, httpwebresponse

I have `httpWebResponse` object. I want to display the `html` text (string) contained in `httWebResponse` object to any element on the webpage using `c#`.

I tried to set `div.innerHtml` property to `html` string. It displays the form view (having buttons, textboxes etc) of the html string. When i click on the button displayed in the div it throws an exception. Also `javascript` is not working in that div. HTML string contains html tags and script associated to some text boxes. I am able to view the controls or form bu can not interact with the form.
How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

buttons is htmlControl? is it type sumbit?try change it type is "button".let me look you code,
otherwise i have difficulty find question .